How does DPI scaling work in Tkinter and embedded Matplotlib figures?
I have a GUI app in built in custom tkinter, that uses a FigureCanvasTkAgg instance to embed a matplotlib figure. I also use a NavigationToolbar2Tk instance..well for navigation.
I all works fine, but I had an issue that if I ran the app on a screen with high DPI, then the buttons on the navigation bar became small relative to the other widgets, as well as the axes of the matplotlib figure.
I tried to figure it out, and searched online, but nothing seemed to work.
In many realated topics I saw this as a suggestion:
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(2)

I tried it and everything turned enlarged and weird. I do not fully understand how this works, as  I couldn't locate the relevant documentation.
But when I changed it:
ctypes.windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(1)

now it works perfectly... Intuitively I would think because the window now takes into consideration the DPI when showing the  widgets, but I do not understand why this works.

Maybe you'll find the required info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellscalingapi/ne-shellscalingapi-process_dpi_awareness.
